# Expandir/recolher conteúdo da tabela ao clicar no título

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma tabela, quero que ao carregar a página ela fique com seu conteúdo oculto, e ao clicar no título (no exemplo abaixo **aguardando**) aí sim carregue o conteúdo, e novamente ao clicar no título o conteúdo se recolha e fique oculto.

Como posso fazer?

```html
  <div class="table-aguardo">
  <div class="header" style="background-color: green;">Aguardando</div>   
   <table cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
         <th>Leito</th>
         <th>Acomodação</th>
         <th>Tempo</th>
         <th>Tipo</th>
         <th width="230">Comentário</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">321</td>
         <td>Apartamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Clínico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">412</td>
         <td>Apartamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Clínico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">110</td>
         <td>Enfermaria</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Cirurgico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">215</td>
         <td>Isolamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Cirurgico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar o método `slideToggle()`. A cada click ele alterna em expande/recolhe o elemento. Mas é preciso que a tabela esteja inicialmente oculta com `display: none` no CSS:

```
table{
   display: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("div.header").click(function(){
   $("table").slideToggle();
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("div.header").click(function(){
   $("table").slideToggle();
});

// Se quiser ajustar a velocidade, pode usar um
// valor em milissegundos. Exemplo:
// $("table").slideToggle(500); // 500 milissegundos
// Significa que a animação vai durar meio segundo.
// Quanto maior o valor, mais lento;
// quanto menor, mais rápido.
// Sem especificar valor, o padrão é de 400.
```

```css
table{
   display: none;
}

div.header{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header" style="background-color: green;">Aguardando</div>   
   <table cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
         <th>Leito</th>
         <th>Acomodação</th>
         <th>Tempo</th>
         <th>Tipo</th>
         <th width="230">Comentário</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">321</td>
         <td>Apartamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Clínico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">412</td>
         <td>Apartamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Clínico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">110</td>
         <td>Enfermaria</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Cirurgico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">215</td>
         <td>Isolamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Cirurgico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
```

> Se quiser alterar o *cursor* do mouse sobre o elemento para o da
>   "mãozinha" (que indica que o elemento é clicável), você pode usar o
>   CSS:

```
div.header{
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Daria para botar uma `mãozinha` quando colocar o mouse em cima do `aguardando` para ficar intuitivo?

Comment: A tal da `mãozinha` adicionada :D

Comment: huahuahuah, coloquei a mãozinha no +1

Comment: ahha... valeu pela mãozinha

Answer (score 2):

Sugestão feita apenas com CSS caso não deseje incluis o jQuery.

```css
.table-aguardo label {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.table-aguardo input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
.table-aguardo input:checked + label {
    background-color: red;
}

.table-aguardo table {
    display: none;
}
.table-aguardo input:checked ~ table {
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-aguardo">
  <input id="aguardando" type="checkbox">
  <label for="aguardando" class="header">Aguardando</label>
   <table cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
         <th>Leito</th>
         <th>Acomodação</th>
         <th>Tempo</th>
         <th>Tipo</th>
         <th width="230">Comentário</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">321</td>
         <td>Apartamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Clínico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">412</td>
         <td>Apartamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Clínico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">110</td>
         <td>Enfermaria</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Cirurgico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">215</td>
         <td>Isolamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Cirurgico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<div class="table-aguardo">
  <input id="finalizado" type="checkbox">
  <label for="finalizado" class="header">Finalizado</label>
   <table cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
         <th>Leito</th>
         <th>Acomodação</th>
         <th>Tempo</th>
         <th>Tipo</th>
         <th width="230">Comentário</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">321</td>
         <td>Apartamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Clínico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">412</td>
         <td>Apartamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Clínico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">110</td>
         <td>Enfermaria</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Cirurgico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
         <td style=" font-size: 3em;">215</td>
         <td>Isolamento</td>
         <td>10:01</td>
         <td>Cirurgico</td>
         <td>TESTE</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```